# Mounting remote directories with the same names (Centos)

Tags: linux, centos, storage, mount, sshfs

I've tried sshfs, but it seems it supports only directories that have different names?
I want to achieve the following and can't seem to find a solution:

```
    (server 1)     (server 2)   (server 1 after mount)
     ["Data"]       ["Data"]         ["Data"]
        |       +       |        =       |
      File 1         File 2        File 1, File 2
```

There are a lot more directories with the same name under "Data", I've just kept it simple. My goal is to merge the folders -
Is this possible and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

sshfs can only mount directories, and you cannot merge directories, but you *can* merge the files and subdirectories individually.

```
Server1:       Server2:       Server3:
  /data/         /data/         /data/         directory
    foo/           bar/           qux/         directory
      foo1           bar1           qux1       file
    file1          file2          file3        file
```

Now create mount directories and mount them using *sshfs*:

```
Server 1:
  /mnt/
    data2  ->  server2:/data
    data3  ->  server3:/data
```

Then merge them with *symbolic links*:

```
Server 1:
  /merged/
    bar     ->  /mnt/data2/bar
    foo     ->  /data/foo
    file1   ->  /data/file1
    file2   ->  /mnt/data2/file2
    file3   ->  /mnt/data3/file3
    qux     ->  /mnt/data3/qux
```

Comment: The problem is that there is around 1TB of content in this "data" folder and all folder (and file) names need to stay the same. The servers are also getting additions in real time, so are sym links really going to work?